# Rspec failed namespace has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my app, one organisation has_many invoices, and organisation doesn't have any namespace, but invoice has Ihub::invoice, and in my organisation model I have

```
  has_many :invoices, class_name: 'Ihub::Invoice'
```

In my controller I have this line, works fine in development:

```
  @invoices = Ihub::Invoice.where(organisation_id: current_organisation.id).page(params[:page])
```

And my rspec failed with this error:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "invoices" does not exist
   LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"invoices"'::regclass
                                             ^
   :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                        pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                   FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                     ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                  WHERE a.attrelid = '"invoices"'::regclass
                    AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                  ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Update

already tried this doesn't help.

```
   RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load
```

Sql query in development

```
   Ihub::Invoice Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "ihub_invoices".* FROM "ihub_invoices" WHERE "ihub_invoices"."organisation_id" = $1  [["organisation_id", 89]]
```

Sql error in rspec (different query Ihub::Invoice.first), but you can see the namespace missing

```
         Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "invoices" does not exist
   LINE 1: SELECT  "invoices".* FROM "invoices"  ORDER BY "invoices"."i...
                                     ^
   : SELECT  "invoices".* FROM "invoices"  ORDER BY "invoices"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: can you paste the SQL from the logs when you execute that query from the development console?

Answer (score 0):

If it works in development but not in test, chances are that your test DB does not contain that table.

Try with:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Its missing the namespace in rspec test, any idea?

Comment: I had to put this in my model to make it working '
    self.table_name = "ihub_invoices"'